# Proof of Quotient-Remainder Theorem by induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I am trying to prove the quotient-remainder theorem by mathematical induction:

> Quotient-Remainder Theorem:
>
> $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, b> 0: \ \exists! q, \ r \in \mathbb{Z}, \
> a = bq \ + \  r, \ r \in [0,b) $

Proof that $ a \in \mathbb{Z} $ exists:

Divide into 2 cases: $ a \ge 0 $ or $ a < 0 $

> Case 1: $ a \ge 0 $
>
> Base Case: Let $ a = 0 $.
>
> It is
>   clear that if we let $ q = r = 0 $, then $ a = b(0) + (0) = 0 $.
>
> Hence,
>   base case is true.
>
> Inductive Step: Assume $ a = k \in \mathbb{Z} $ exists
>
> Hence, $ k = bq + r $
>
> Proof: Let $ a = k + 1\in \mathbb{Z} $
>
> By inductive hypothesis, $ k = bq + r $
>
> Hence, $ k + 1 = bq + r + 1 $ and $ k + 1 = bq + (r + 1) $ where
>   $ r + 1 \in \mathbb{Z} $
>
> by
>   closure property of integers
>
> Thus, $ \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}, a \ge 0 \ $, $ a = bq + r $
>
> Case 2: $ a < 0 $
>
> Base Case: Let $ a = -1 $.
>
> It is clear that if we let $ q = 0 $ and $ r = -1 $, then $ a = b(0) + (-1) = -1 $.
>
> Hence, base case is true.
>
> Inductive Step: Assume $ a = k \in \mathbb{Z} $ exists
>
> Hence, $ k = bq + r $
>
> Proof: Assume $ a = -(k + 1) \in \mathbb{Z} $
>
> By
>   inductive hypothesis, $ k = bq + r $
>
> Hence, $ k + 1 = bq + r + 1 $ and $ -(k + 1) = b(-q) + (-r - 1) $ where
>
> $ -r - 1 \in \mathbb{Z} $ by closure property of integers
>
> Thus, $ \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}, a < 0 \ $, $ a = bq + r $

I am not sure if my proof is correct. Also, I do not know how to prove $ r \in [0,b) $ and the uniqueness of $ q $ and $ r $. Could someone please advise me?

Comment: Try to write down the first few steps of your proof. You'll  realize that what's proved is $a = 0 \cdot b + a$, which is true of course, but it's not the quotient-remainder theorem you were trying to prove.

Comment: Two problems.  You haven't proven uniqueness.  And you induction proves for all a; a =0b + a.  You did not take into account that r+1 might >= b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your induction case didn't take $r+1=b $ into account and in the end all you proved was $a=0b+a $.

Do this: assume $a=qb+r;0\le r <b $.  If $r <b-1$ then $a+1 = qb + (r+1) $.  And if $r=b-1$ then $a+1 =qb +r+1 =qb+b= (q+1)b+0$.

So if $a =qb +r;r\in [0,b) $ has solution the $a+1=pb+s;s\in [0,b) $ has solution.

One can do the same for $a-1$.  If $a=qb+r$ and $r > 0$ then $a-1= qb +(r-1) $ is a solution.  If $r=0$ then $a-1= (q-1)b +(b-1) $ is a solution.

But I haven't shown they are unique.  You can show uniqueness via induction and I spent a long time in my rough draft showing just that.  But in the end it was unnecessarily complicated and confusing and, frankly bizarre.  (I'll leave it in as a post script.)  It's much better to show uniqueness directly.

Suppose $a=qb+r=pq+s $ then $(r-s)=(p-q)b $.  If $r,s \in [0,b) $ then $-b < r-s =(p-q)b <b $.  So $-1 < p-q < 1$ so $p-q=0;p=q $ and $r=s $.

So solutions are unique.

=== postscript: bizarre rough draft==

Base step.  Need to show $0=0b + 0$ is unique.

Proof: (assume all variables in this post are integers.)

If $0=qb +r$ then $r = -qb $.  If $q \le -1$ the $r \ge b $ which isn't acceptable.  If $q >0$ then $r < 0$ which isn't acceptable.  So $0,0$ is unique solution.

Induction case.

$a=qb+r $ is unique solution.

Let $a+1 = pb +s;0\le s <b $ be an acceptable solution (if there is one, which we need to be aware there might not be).

Then $a = pb + s-1;-1\le s-1 < b-1 $.  If $s -1 \ge 0$ then $p=q $ and $s=r+1$ (and $r < b-1$) as $p,r $ was a unique solution.  So $p=q;s=r+1$ *would* be a solution and it would be unique.

But it *is* a solution.  So it is unique

Otherwise if our hypothetical solution had $s=0$ then it would follow $r= b-1$. We would have $a+1 = pq +0 = qb +r+1= qb+b =(q+1)b $ and so $p=q+1$ and $s=0$.  That would have to be the solution and it would be unique.

But it *is* a solution.  So it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite correct.  In your line for the case $a > 0$,
"Hence, $k+1=bq+r+1$ and $k+1=bq+(r+1)$ where $r+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$", $r+1$ may be equal to $b$ which violates the statement of the theorem. So you need to add,
"If $r+1=b$, then choose $q = q+1$ and $r=0$."  A similar statement is necessary in your other inductive step.

Comment: Yup. I understand that r + 1 may be equal to b. r + 1 is the remainder in this case i.e. y = r + 1 < b

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to prove the quotient-remainder theorem by mathematical induction

It's not clear from the context whether the emphasis is on "*by induction*" or on "*prove the quotient-remainder theorem*".

If the latter, then the intuition is that $\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \{k b, k b + 1, k b + 2, ..., k b + (b-1)\}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ for $b \in \mathbb{N}^+$, since it's a union of adjacent,  non-overlapping sets of consecutive $b$ integers each. It follows that any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ will fall into exactly *one* such set $\{k b, k b + 1, k b + 2, ..., k b + (b-1)\}$, so taking $q = k, r = a - q b$ proves the proposition, both existence and unicity.

Comment: My emphasis is on using proof by induction

Comment: I am not sure how to prove my induction though. Are you able to give me some hints to start with?

Comment: @LanceHAOH See the other answer posted already. As long as $r+1 \lt b$ your construction works. But when you reach the next multiple of $b$ the proof as written now keeps incrementing $r$ so that it reaches $r+1=b$ and goes outside the target interval $[0,b)$. Instead, you need to increment $q$ and reset $r$ to 0. For uniqueness, assume there are two such distinct representations, and try to derive a contradiction.